# Removing an object from RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

When using ListView, I could easily delete an item from the adapter by writing `this.adapter.delete(mYeets.get(position))`. With RecyclerView, is there an equivalent? Or does notifying the adapter of a change all that I have to do now?

```
private void deleteComment(int position) {
    String currentUserObjectId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<>("Yeet");
    query.whereEqualTo(ParseConstants.KEY_OBJECT_ID, mYeets.get(position).getObjectId());
    query.whereContains(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_ID, currentUserObjectId);
    query.findInBackground((yeet, e) -> {
        if (e == null) {

            for (ParseObject yeetObject : yeet) {

                if (yeetObject.getParseObject(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_AUTHOR_POINTER).getObjectId().equals((ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId()))) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete");
                    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Do you want to delete this Yeet?");
                    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialog, which) -> {

                        // Iterate over all messages and delete them
                        for (ParseObject delete : yeet) {

                            delete.deleteInBackground();

                            //this.adapter.delete(mYeets.get(position));
                            this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Yeet deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    });
                    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", (dialog, which) -> {
                    });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You have to remove from list and then notifydatasetchanged to adapter.

Comment: ``delete.deleteInBackground();`` will remove the data. Is that the same as removing it from the adapter? Or is there another command? I can't to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply removing the item from the data structure (List) used by the RecyclerView.Adapter and then calling its [notifyItemRemoved()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRemoved(int)) should be the best way.

The previously suggested [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) unnecessarily invalidates every single item in the list, rather than only those located after the deleted item.

Answer (score 1):

If your are using RecyclerView, Just delete the item from the list and Call the method notifiyDataSetChanged;

Comment: Okay so it appears that I am already doing that with ``delete.deleteInBackground();``. Thanks.

Comment: This is exactly what first comment of original post says.

Comment: I'm not at a computer where I can deploy my code so I had to ask. I was just wondering if there was something else I had to do but I guess not. Thanks.

Comment: You can add a method for deleting a row to your Adapter. Let me know if you want me to help you.

Comment: I'm confused. Is deleting the object in my database and notifying the adapter data change not enough?

Comment: Anyway , you have some list to display right, whether its coming from server or DB, after setting the data to the adapter. Just remove the item from the list and notifiy.

Comment: That would be enough, but if you can do that several time, it would be better that make it a method inside your adapter.